# Non-www RewriteRule not working on request URI

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a website to have all URLs NOT have www in front of it. For this, I have found some useful bits of code here that have helped me out a lot. However, nowhere can I find how to properly do it for ALL request URIs. Currently it only works on the domains homepage.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>


# END WordPress
```

Right now www.domain.nl gets rewritten into domain.nl. However, any other like www.domain.nl/anything_else do not get rewritten (also tried adding a / before the %{REQUEST_URI}, did not work).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With www rule before:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.nl%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```